# How to easily iterate over all strings within the "strings.xml" resource file?

Tags: android, android-resources

I created an application that uses the TTS engine to send feedback to the user. With the aim to improve the performance, I used the `synthesizeToFile` and `addSpeech` methods, but strings of text to be synthesized are inside the `strings.xml` file, so I have to invoke these methods for each string that is spoken by the TTS engine.

Since the TTS engine uses only strings whose name begins with `tts_`, is it possible to easily iterate over all strings that begin with `tts_` within the `strings.xml` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give them all (while defining) the resource name as `"prefix"+(1..n)`. And in the code use,

```
int resid=<constant>;
for(i=1;resid!=0;i++){
        resid = this.getResources().getIdentifier("prefix"+i, "strings", this.getPackageName());
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can get all the strings in strings.xml via reflection, and filter out only the ones you need, like so:

```
for (Field field : R.string.class.getDeclaredFields())
{
  if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && !Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers()) && field.getType().equals(int.class))
  {
    try
    {
      if (field.getName().startsWith("tts_"))
      {
        int id = field.getInt(null);
        // do something here...
      }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
      // ignore
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
      // ignore
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but provided that it works, THIS is the answer to the question, not the accepted one, which would only work in the ridiculous case where the names tts_1, tts_2, etc were acceptable.

Comment: Could you please specify which Field class is this? Is it java.lang.reflect.Field?

Comment: Yes, it's java.lang.reflect.Field. It should be easy to find, since it's the return type of `class.getDeclaredFields()`

Comment: Is it possible to get the strings of all modules (each R file exists in a different package) ? And, how do I get it for each language?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, but you must know ahead of time (i.e. hard-code) all the different R classes in each package (e.g. `for (Field field : com.example.foo.R.string.class.getDeclaredFields())`). There are ways around that too, but they are substantially more complicated than this.

Comment: @androiddeveloper To get it for each language, you have to play around with resources after you have the list of IDs; you will need to call `Context.createConfigurationContext()` to create a new context for each locale (you can call `Context.getAssets().getLocales()` to find out what languages you have), and use that context to retrieve the resources for each ID you find using the method above,

Comment: @LoganPickup I see. Can you please share this answer here, then: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42806443/878126 ?

Answer (score 2):

You could put these TTS strings into a [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
String[] strings = getResources().getAssets().list("string");
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
                Log.d("aaa ", strings[i]);
            }
```

to iterate through other resources like fonts,... just replace string with folder name.

Answer (score -1):

In all my projects, i just observed that the value of strings in R.java starts with `0x7f050000` and it counts upwards, like `0x7f050001, 0x7f050002, 0x7f050003,`....

You could just `++` them :D

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You cannot assume that it starts from 0x7f050000 if your code hase arrays.xml attr.xml than sometimes it varies.. you are correct that it gives incremental ids but lowest id you can not assume.