# How to get the keys and values of an xml string resource

Tags: java, android

```
<string id="I want To Get This">and this</string>
<string id="I want To Get This">and this</string>
<string id="I want To Get This">and this</string>
```

How to get the value

Comment: you're asking how to get the keys and values out of an xml string resource, correct ?

Comment: Yes  and add it list map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Comment: You have to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first. Your question is clearly bad. This is site where you can ask for advice, hint or small block of code. But you have to show us some effort and not only ask for complete solution / code.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value from String Resource you use

```
String stringToCompare= getString(R.string.my_custom_id);
```

After that you can add that value to a list

```
myList.add(value)
```

Now if you say all similar I suppose you mean equal values or at least same characters. For that you could iterate over all the string values via reflection

```
for (Field field : R.string.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
 if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && !Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers()) && field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
   try {
     if (field.getName().toLoweCase().equals(stringToCompare.toLowerCase())) {
       int id = field.getInt(null);
       myList.add(getString(id))
     }
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // ignore
   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     // ignore
    }
  }
}
```

Or can find another way of doing that iteration here [How to easily iterate over all strings within the "strings.xml" resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633456/how-to-easily-iterate-over-all-strings-within-the-strings-xml-resource-file)